# ASP.NET MVC different routing for different actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am building a Site using ASP.NET MVC. In `RouteConfig`, I modified the method like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{Director}/{Movie}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Movies", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, Director = UrlParameter.Optional, Movie = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );

     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default2",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Movies", action = "Create", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );            
}
```

And in IndexView, I coded like:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Director>

<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @foreach (var movie in item.Movies)
                {
                    <div style="width: 100%;">
                        @Html.ActionLink(movie.Title, "Index", new { Director = movie.Director.Name, Movie = movie.Title }, null)
                    </div>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Actually I modified `RouteConfig` because I want different URLs for different directors and different movies in order to satisfy our client's `SEO requirement`.

It is working fine for the `Index` Action but even when I tried to invoke `Create` action using `@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")`, it still invokes `Index` action. According to my understanding so far, it should invoke `Create` Action. I am new to MVC so sorry if my question seems foolish.  But what major thing, I am missing here?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")` - this will generates a url. While hovering with the mouse, you can see it at the bottom of the browser. Can you please share the url generated ?

Comment: @VeeKayBee I hover over the ActionLink and at bottom it showed : http://localhost:#myportnumber/

Comment: that is the reason it is going to index. It supposed to be like `http://localhost:<portnmber>/<cntrollername>/create`. The mentioned url will always point to default route that is index action will be fired always.

Comment: But I have defined @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") why it is still pointing to index?

Comment: try with @Html.ActionLink("Movies","Create")

Comment: Tried but no luck. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Routeconfig is checked top down.

**Update**: You should specify the controller name in the route otherwise the way your routeconfig was in your question, Default2 would never have been fired.Having 2 routes start with {something} means the second one won't be fired. I'm guessing you want your URL to be `localhost/movies/create/id`. For that, do this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "MoviesDefault",
         url: "Movies/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Movies", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );  

     /* not sure about this route without testing - 
     /* i think it would conflict with the above route
     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "MovieDirector",
         url: "Movies/{Director}/{Movie}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Movies", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, Director = UrlParameter.Optional, Movie = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
     */

     // for this following route, i've left 'Movies' as the controller, but it should be 
     // your 'home page' controller. As in, whatever your default http://localhost:port/ should be.
     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Movies", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     ); 
}
```

Comment: I moved Default2 at top, Now it is invoking Create Action on load.

Comment: Did you checked the other action. Because if you specify like this it will automatcally send all the routes to `Movies` cntroller and `Create` action.

Comment: I tried to invoke Edit action using @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit"), it is changing the URL http://localhost:port/Movies/Edit but still invoking Index method.

Comment: try this action:
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "Movies")

Comment: @UsmanKhalid that is because you need to modify the url pattern for each route. Can you please try modifying the url pattern . I believe we cannot have same url pattern for multiple routes.

Comment: @rudeovskizebear I think now its works :) ! also can you please review my suggestion below.

Comment: My first most requirement is I need urls after the name of Director/Movie like www.oursite.com/james-cameron/titanic/. That's why i modified the RegisterRoutes method. So above mentioned code will not fulfill my requirement. :(

Comment: That's probably not the best route strategy to use. But you could try removing 'Movies/' from the 'url:' in the second route and see if it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please modify as per this and check.

I believe when the url is

```
//http://localhost/Movies/Create/1 -> invokes Movies controller and Create action.

 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
         routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
         routes.MapRoute(
             name: "MoviesCreate",
             url: "Movies/{Movies}/Create/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Movies", action = "Create", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );    
//http://Movies/JCameron/Titanic/12 -> invokes Movies controller and Index action.

         routes.MapRoute(
             name: "MoviesHome",
             url: "Movies/{Director}/{Movie}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Movies", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, Director = UrlParameter.Optional, Movie = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );

}
```

I am not 100% sure, you need some modification. But you cannot pass a similar type of url pattern and invoke two controllers.

As per the code in your question it will invokes always the first route, if the url matches. And you are using same pattern to second route also. SO second route always hidden. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Now I modified the Route : 
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{Director}/{Movie}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Movies", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, Director = UrlParameter.Optional, Movie = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default2",
                url: "{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Movies", action = "Create", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
Still no luck. :(

Comment: Can you please check the way I suggested, there are some issues with the url you mentioned. Can you pls copy the url pattern as I shown in my code. Please try using the same pattern